# How to send email with attachment on OpenWRT?

Tags: email, command-line, openwrt

I have installed OpenWRT on my ruter with msmtp package.
I'm able to send regular email but I can't figure out how to add attachment.
I've searched google and it seems that I should use uuencode but I can't find proper package.

The questions are:

1. does uuencode or it's substitute exists for OpenWRT? If not then:
2. How to send email with attachment on OpenWRT without uuencode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mutt. Here is an example how to send an email with attachment:

```
echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a "/path/to/file.to.attach" -s "subject of message" -- recipient@domain.com
```

As of OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment 12.09 the mutt package is available.